# ID Token for Google log in with Firebase for Android

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to send some data from my Android app to Firebase. I'm using the built in Google account log in with Firebase by following the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in). From the guide linked [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#send-the-id-token-to-your-server) it seems that there is some extra steps to verify the user is who they say they are. However, the guide talks about the developer using their own authentication server which I am not doing. This line particularly does not make sense in my application here as I do not have a web client id.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
    .requestEmail()
    .build();
```

Do I need to use OAuth? I'm assuming using just the account ID to identify users is not secure as stated in the guide.